# WP Rest API v2.0 user profile update issue

Tags: plugins, json, rest-api

I'm using WP Rest API plugin to use Wordpress as backend of iOS app. I need to update the username using the following endpoint

```
http://......com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1?context=edit
```

And this is the response I got.

```
{
  "code": "rest_cannot_edit",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit resource.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

It seems that the Rest API plugin does not support user profile update, or am I missing some authentication parameters?

Thanks in advance, looking forward the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from below.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Authentication is the primary step for all API works.